# Best practice for template setup in Elm or Phoenix

Tags: elm, apache-phoenix

I am using elm for front-end and phoenix as back-end.
What is the best practices to create template which will be inherited by all  pages? SHould it be implemented in phoenix or elm.
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elm doesn't use the concept of *pages* nor *templates* for HTML rendering. Instead it uses functions. And being a pure functional programming language, inheritance doesn't apply to Elm.

Having said that, you can simulate the inheritance-*like* behaviour you'd get from say... SiteMesh, with Elm functions. (Note: SiteMesh uses the decorator design pattern most prominently, so it's not actually inheritance). Here's an example (I'm kinda winging it here):

```
template : Model -> (Model -> Html Msg) -> (Model -> Html Msg) -> (Model -> Html Msg) -> Html Msg
template model header body footer =
    body [] 
        [ div [ class 'header' ] (header model)
        , div [ class 'body' ] (body model)
        , div [ class 'footer' ] (footer model)
    ]

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    let
        header model = p [] [ text "This is the header" ]
        body model = p [] [ text "This is the body" ]
        footer model = p [] [ text "This is the footer" ]
    in
        template model header body footer
```

In the example above, the `template` function takes a model and three functions. Each of the three functions are responsible for rendering a portion of the view (or *page*). This means the `template` function can be used to render common content, and the functions provided to it can then handle the custom content.